# How to run AutoHotKey scripts on several PCs at once, controlled from one place?

Tags: autohotkey

For some load testing simulations, I'm looking at scripting with AHK 1.1. The issue is we have a client-server setup with multiple workstations so I'd really like to be able to trigger the same script (or even variations) to run on multiple PCs at once, to accurately simulate multiple users all hammering the system.

Even more useful would be to make sure the same test happens at exactly (within some tolerance) the same time, to check this doesn't cause problems.

What be would the best way to do this? Do it from within AHK itself, or use some separate remote-control tool to let me fire off scripts on PCs of my choosing?

Answer (score 2):

With ahk you will need scripts acting as server and clients so both needs to be running no matter the method used...

As to the TCP/IP you can do this, you just need to find out if you have any usable/open posts your scripts can use...

I just helped an australian guy the other day setup a great working lot of server/client scripts

using the [Socket Class](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/94376-socket-class-%C3%BCberarbeitet/) by Bentschi looking something like this

**Server:**

```
;Server

#include Socket.ahk

myTcp := new SocketTCP()
myTcp.bind("addr_any", 54321)
myTcp.listen()
myTcp.onAccept := Func("OnTCPAccept")
return

OnTCPAccept(this)
{
    newTcp := this.accept()
    newTcp.onRecv := func("OnTCPRecv")
    newTcp.sendText("Connected")
}

OnTCPRecv(this)
{
    msgbox % this.recvText()
}
```

**Client:**

```
;Client

#include Socket.ahk

myTcp := new SocketTCP()
myTcp.connect("your servers A_IPAddress1", 54321) ; lokal
myTcp.onRecv := Func("OnTcpRecv")
return

OnTcpRecv(this)
{
    ToolTip % this.RecvText()
}
```

But to use and or set something like this up you may need to know what ports are usable on the network or have the ability to change settings as needed.

The speed of the TCP/IP scripts are in the low milliseconds (under 20 on my network) so no real tolerance to speak of.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As wrote [Sidola](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27188901/1601703) you can check shared folder for some file or folder. You can use 
[IfExist](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExist.htm) command for it. Here is example:

```
Loop
{
        IfExist, c:\a.txt
        {
                break
        }
}
;code to execute if c:\a.txt exists comes below.
MsgBox, 1
```

Also you can add [Sleep](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Sleep.htm) command to put less stress on hdd like for example in code below:

```
Loop
{
        IfExist, c:\a.txt
        {
                break
        }
        Sleep, 1000
}
;code to execute if c:\a.txt exists comes below.
MsgBox, 1
```

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Comment: Doesn't this approach mean AHK has to be running on all the machines in the first place though?

Comment: @Mr.Boy this script should be run all PCs that you want to automate. So, yes. you should run it on all remote machines.

Comment: @Mr.Boy I am sure there are also other ways to control automation of remote PC (like TCP/IP and etc.) but I think the above way is the easiest one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide actual code, but there is a way to kind of inject a service into your LAN machines through the Admin$ share and remotely control it. This way AHK wouldn't need to run on the LAN computers all the time.
I don't know how exactly this could be done, but PsShutdown does it to hibernate LAN PCs which is normally impossible.

In case you actually manage to do it, it would be great if you could share it.